# Closed subvarieties

Tags: algebraic-geometry

I am studying from the book Görtz and Wedhorn. In page 25, the following is mentioned:

Let $((X,\mathcal{O}_X)$ be a prevariety and let $Z\subseteq X$ be an irreducible closed subset. Let $U$ be an open subset of $Z$. Define
$${\mathcal{O}'}_Z(U)=\left\{f\in Map(U,k)\mid \forall x\in U:\exists x\in V\subseteq X\quad open, g\in \mathcal{O}_X(V)\colon f\mid_{U\cap V}=g\mid_{U\cap V} \right\}. $$

It claims that $(Z,{\mathcal{O}'}_Z)$ is a space of function. I can not prove the gluing,although it seems easy. Is there any guidance?

Comment: There is something wrong with your definition, one could take $U = V$ and then $O'_Z(U) = O_X(U)$. In fact $Z$ do not appears.

Comment: @Nicolas Hemelsoet: You cannot always take $U=V$ as $U$ is not necessarily open in $X$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We want to show that given open  subsets  $U_i\subseteq Z$  and $f_i\in \mathcal{O}'_Z(U_i)$,  $i\in I$, with

$$f_{i|{U_i\cap U_j}}=f_{j|{U_i\cap U_j}} $$

for all $i,j\in I$ the unique function $f:\bigcup_i U_i\to  k$ with $f_{|U_i}=f_i$ lies in 
$\mathcal{O}'_Z(\bigcup_i U_i)$.

Note that the $U_i$ are assumed to be open in $Z$ (not necessarily in $X$!) and set $U=\bigcup_i U_i$. To check $f\in \mathcal{O}'_Z(U)$ assume $x\in U$.

Then $x\in U_i$ for some $i\in I$. As $f_i\in \mathcal{O}'_Z(U_i)$ there is $  V'\subseteq X$ open in $X$ with $x\in V'$ and  $g'\in  \mathcal{O}_X(V')$ such that $f_i{_{|{U_i\cap V'}}}=g'{_{|{U_i\cap V'}}}$. As $U_i$ is open in $Z$ there is $U_i'\subseteq X$ open in $X$ with $U_i=U_i'\cap Z$.

Now set $V=U_i'\cap V' $ and $g=g'_{|V}$. Then $V$ is open in $X$ with $x\in V$ and we have  $g\in\mathcal{O}_X(V)$ by the axiom of restriction. 
Then as $U_i\subseteq U\subseteq Z$ we have$$U\cap V=U\cap Z\cap U_i'\cap V'=U_i\cap V'$$

which implies $f_{|U\cap V}=f_{|U_i\cap V'}=f_i{_{|{U_i\cap V'}}}=g'{_{|{U_i\cap V'}}}=g'{_{|{U\cap V}}}=g{_{|{U\cap V}}}$, 
so $f\in \mathcal{O}'_Z(U)$